# Can you parse an int from a sqlite database that was originally a bool, back into a bool after querying the database?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am currently getting a User from a sqlite database I created where I am going to use the data in a FutueBuilder. Now when I store the User data there is a Bool that gets stored in the sqlite database, since sqlite doesn't support boolean types, this gets turned into an int. When I query the user data table, and then run the data through a function that uses the User object to turn the queried data into a user object, it errors out, since the function expects a Boolean, and not an int. What can I do to get around this?

This is where I query the user data table, then send the result to the function to get added to my user list

```
  Future<dynamic> getUser() async {
    List _user =[];
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.query("user");
    if (res.length == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    else {
      var resMap = res[0];
      return _user.add(User.fromJson(resMap));
    }
  }
```

This is the user model and the function that will convert the data into a User object for me. This is where it has an issue due to the model expecting a boolean, but the database now passes it an int since it converted the original boolean to an int.

```
User userFromJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));


class User {

  bool success;

  String userID;

  String firstName;

  String lastName;

  String email;


  User({this.success, this.userID, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      success: json['success'],
      userID: json['UserID'],
      firstName: json['FirstName'],
      lastName: json['LastName'],
      email: json['Email'],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a ternary operator on your User.fromJson function. Take a look:

```
factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      success = json['success'] == 1 ? true : false,
      userID = json['UserID'],
      firstName = json['FirstName'],
      lastName = json['LastName'],
      email = json['Email'],
    );
  }
```

This way if the value is 1 it will set the value to true and if is 0 (or any other value) will set the value to false.